# change of Public file system path

Tags: files

how can i change Public file system path in drupal 8 ? And can you tell more about how to increase the storage of database?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i change Public file system path in Drupal 8?

You can add the following line to either your `settings.php` file, or your `settings.local.php` file. E.g. `docroot/sites/default/settings.php`

```
$settings['file_public_path']  = '/sites/default/files/my_custom_folder';
```

> And can you tell more about how to increase the storage of database?

I have no idea what this means.